# Most efficient way to remove these objects

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to loop through a set of `Users`, and remove them from another set `LostFollowers` (if they exist). `Users` are identifiable by `id`.

```
struct LostFollower {
  let user: User
  let dateLost: Date
}

let users1: Set<LostFollower> = // …
let users2: Set<User> = // …

users2.forEach { user in
  // Need to remove anyone in the set users1, whose `user` property is equal to user
}
```

How can I do this? Will I need to use `filter` or is there a better way to do it?

Note: Set operations won't work because `users1` and `users2` are of different types.

Comment: This is called subtraction (for sets), and there’s already a method on Set that does exactly this. Check out the documentation for Set.

Comment: @Alexander I know about that, but that would require `users1` and `users2` to be of the same type, no?

Comment: I didn’t notice that. You should have mentioned in your question that you already tried that.

Comment: Does your domain have a way to convert from one of those types to the other? If so, you could use that to create a new temporary set that you can use with the subtraction. Alternatively, you can call `users.removeAll(where: { user in usersToRemove.contains(where:  user.id == $0.id })`, but that’s quadratic and harder to read.

Comment: No it doesn't unfortunately... hmm.

Comment: If performance is a concern, you can use that last snippet I gave, but transform `usersToRemove: Set<User>` into `userIDsToRemove: Set<User.ID>`, and then use that for fast `contains` checks within that `users.removeAll` call. It would be linear time overall, but incur some overhead up front. It’s only worth doing for larger data sets

Comment: The removeAll(where:) seems to only exist on arrays. Converting a set to an array would occur another O(n) overhead wouldn't it? Also, I'd need to map the ids which would be another overhead which wouldn't outweigh the smaller overhead of checking bools. Unless I'm mistaken

Comment: Ignore the second part of that comment, I misunderstood what you'd written

Comment: Oh, I thought removeAll exists for all collections. None the less, you can do the next closest thing if `X = X.filter(…)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if i understand the question correctly, you're trying to remove elements from users1 ( set of LostFollowers ) if they exists in users2.
I think you can do something like this

```
let filteredUser = users1.filter { follower in 
    !users2.contains(follower.user)
}
```

Comment: added the example here : https://pastecode.io/s/kmqft9qu

Comment: Great answer and I thought there would be a filter function but couldn’t figure it out. Thanks for that

Answer (score 0):

```
let filtered = users2.subtracting(users1.map { $0.user })
```